# Bind children of children in SAPUI5 table

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have this model from my oData service:

```
{
  "entity": [
    {
      "valueA": "ABC",
      "valueB": "DEF",
      "childL1": [
        {
          "valueC": "GHI",
          "valueD": "JKL"
        },
        {
          "valueC": "MNO",
          "valueD": "PQR"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "valueA": "ABC",
      "valueB": "DEF",
      "childL1": [
        {
          "valueC": "GHI",
          "valueD": "JKL"
        },
        {
          "valueC": "MNO",
          "valueD": "PQR"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that for each 'child' in my 'entity' set, there's also an array of possible 'childL1'.

I have table in UI5 and I bound the data in the controller by:

```
this.myTable.bindAggregation('items', {path: /entity, template: this.oTemplate});
```

This works but the table displays:

```
Child1
Child2
```

However, what I want to do is:

```
/0/ChildL1/0
/0/ChildL1/0
/1/ChildL1/0
/1/ChildL1/0
```

So, to do that, I can do:

```
this.myTable.bindAggregation('items', {path: /entity/childL1, template: this.oTemplate});
```

The result would be as expected. However, I need to also display `valueA` in my table. Since my binding is at child1, I won't be able to get /entity/n/valueA.

What possible solution can I do for this? Is there a way to backtrack provided that childL1 has a 'key'? Or can I get `entity` then display `childL1` in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned table control like which control you are using - sap.ui.table.Table or sap.m.Table. In case of "sap.ui.table.Table" you can bind the individual column like below

```
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
          label : new sap.m.Label({
            text : " "
          }),
          template : new sap.m.Text({
            maxLines : 1
          }).bindProperty("text", "valueA"),
          }));
 oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
          label : new sap.m.Label({
            text : " "
          }),
          template : new sap.m.Text({
            maxLines : 1
          }).bindProperty("text", "childL1/valueC"),
          }));
```

Like this you can add any no. of columns with different path but their parent path should alsways be same and then at last you can bind your main path to table rows like this-

```
oTable.bindAggregation("rows", {
          path : "/entity"
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

and in case of sap.m.Table you can do it like this-

```
new sap.m.Table({   items:{
                        path:"/entity",
                        template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                            cells:[
                                new sap.m.Text({
                                    text:"{valueA}"
                                }),
                                new sap.m.Text({
                                    text: "{childL1/valueC}"
                                })
                            ]
                        })
                    }
                })
```